# dompdf HTML to PDF - can't set margin of page

Tags: php, html, css, margin, dompdf

version: 0.6.0 beta 3

I tryed in every manner to make dompdf set the margin of the page. I have a long page with a lot of text, divided in chapters...

my css is something like:

```
#wrapper{
    padding:8px;
}

/* other styles... */

@page{margin: 0.2in 0.5in 0.2in 0.5in;}
```

when the php is

```
<?php
ob_start(); // begin collecting output
include 'makemypdf.php'; // this page output the html
$html = ob_get_clean(); // retrieve output from makemypdf.php and stop buffering


require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

?>
```

but what I get is a page with NO margins!!! only the padding of the #wrapper are applied... and they are applyed only at the beginning and at the end of the entire PDF...

I'm doing something wrong?

PS - it seems that only the bottom-margin is applied... but I'm not sure...

PPS - I tryed with no success also this css:
    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    html {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    @page {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

Comment: try using `<tag style="margin: 0.2in 0.5in 0.2in 0.5in;"></tag>` as `<body style="margin: 0.2in 0.5in 0.2in 0.5in;"></body>`

Comment: thank you for your answer! I figured out what I "was doing wrong" after a few steps today. I've post the solution.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I figured out that neither body or @page works in this version of dompdf.

the problem was in the main CSS, where I put every tyme this line:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
```

I find out that margins of the PDF are decided in base of the margin of the HTML, so I removed that line with the global selector and replaced with:

```
th,td,p,div,b ... {margin:0;padding:0}
html{margin:40px 50px}
```

This works as "un-expected" and I get the right margin in every page.

Comment: There does appear to be an issue with using `*` and attempting to set page margins. We'll need to look into it. You can still use the `*` selector, just force the page margins by appending `!important`, e.g. `@page { margin: 40px 50px !important; }`.

Comment: FYI, dompdf considers the HTML element and `@page` to be the same. There is a bug in v0.6.0 beta 3 where you had to [include a space after the `@page` selector](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/614). It has been fixed for the next release.

Comment: You're welcome. I need to amend my statement about @page vs. the HTML element. I don't think they're the same, but affect the document in similar ways. We'll need to decide if we want those two selectors to represent the same entity.

Answer (score 11):

This fixed my problem:

```
        @page {
            margin: 0 !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it on body tag, like that : `body { margin: 0.2cm; }`